# why are my getting the red underlined error in my code under "Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2" even when my code is correct?

Tags: java, android, variables

why are my getting the red underlined error in my code under "Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2" even when my code is correct?

This is my code:

[image]

Comment: Please attach your actual code rather than a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

No, your code is not correct. You are doing assignment `x()/2 = y()`  which makes no sense as you cannot assign anything to numeric value (which your lvalue is) and that's solely the reason it gets underlined as erroneous. This is simply invalid syntax in java. Shouldn't it be a  coma `,` rather than `=` or whole lvalue completely removed?